# "A generic error occurred in GDI+" while using MeasureString

Tags: c#, gdi+, measurestring

I have an overriden (WinForms) MemoEdit control (unfortunately I can't give you the code).
If I enter more than 32000 characters, it raises an error "A generic error occurred in GDI+"
I thought that there's an error (exception) in my control but then I tested on a simple WinForm application this code:

```
var myString = new string('G', 32001);
var g = this.CreateGraphics();
g.MeasureString(myString, Font, 1000);
```

and it crashes with the same exactly error
Does anyone know why this happens or where is specified this constant of 32000 ? I couldn't find anything useful on Google.

Comment: Which font and size are you using?

Comment: On my computer, it works all the way up to `65535`. It breaks on `65536`

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a new bug which was introduced in Windows 8. I would be curious as to the behaviour in an older version of Windows:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776722/label-control-throws-an-exception-if-its-text-is-set-to-a-very-long-string

Comment: This link is broken.  Any idea if there's a new link to this issue?

Comment: They don't want to fix it, is my understanding. The last two posts can be found on a cached version of the web page. http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:LHbEaBO6c-EJ:https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776722/label-control-throws-an-exception-if-its-text-is-set-to-a-very-long-string

Comment: Thanks for the link to the cached page, Frank.  Well, that doesn't bode well for the new bug report I just opened a couple days ago (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1850428/graphics-measurestring-throws-exceptions-for-long-strings-in-win8-didnt-in-previous-versions-of-windows).  We're running into this issue on any Win8 or later machine, which seems to jive with this other bug post's explanation.  I haven't gotten a response yet from MS, but I'm doubtful I'll like their answer...

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that the string width exceeds Int32.Max (you could maybe refer to [this thread](http://www.telerik.com/forums/gdi-error-in-system-drawing-graphics-measurestring)).

I know that your error occures if you use a language as Arabic which involves special characters (see [MSDN-Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): `For bidirectional languages, such as Arabic, the string length must not exceed 2046 characters`).

To solve your problem I would suggest splitting the string every 31999th character and add the different sizes/lengths.

Comment: 32000 != 32k. Also: it is the MeasureString that crahes, not the string assignment..

Comment: @TaW: I know that, I meant that the string width **in pixel** larger is than Int32

Comment: Yeah, well, it is curious though: 32000 does work and 32001 does not. There is no string width in pixel other than the 1000 pixels he feeds into the MeasureString. And the resulting height (which is what he actually measures) is a few hundred pixels, depending on the font. The sources lead into a core routine, passing in the length as int.. rather weird.

Comment: I'm using English as a language. I haven't tried any other languages.